# Save the answer in TeX/PDF - revisioned

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, export, user-scripts

Some time ago, I used the **Save as LaTeX** script which was provided by the user who answered this question [Save the answer in TEX?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15230/save-the-answer-in-tex). It worked really well.

Unfortunately the user seems to have deleted all accounts here at *Stackexchange* and also the associated *Dropbox* and *GitHub* ones where the script was uploaded which leaves me with no satisfying alternative. I know of [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) from this answer [Save the answer in PDF?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf), but I really would like to get the LaTeX source as well (I also liked the way **Save as LaTeX** after printing)

Does anyone know something similar which would do the trick or has anyone a cached copy of the suberb script mentioned above - as long this wouldn't harm any copyrights?

Comment: Could perhaps some versions [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://normalhuman.github.io/savetex/) help to recover (some version) of the script? Perhaps also some [other useful scripts and bookmarklets](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://normalhuman.github.io/*) can be found there.

Comment: @MartinSleziak that's great! works perfectly, though I don't know for how long (it will be archived), but one could save it for offline use I guess.

Comment: The script seems to be available here now: https://normalhuman.github.io/savetex/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comment by @Martin Sleziak basically answered my question. I recovered the script through [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119113919/http://normalhuman.github.io/savetex/) using the most up-to-date archived version. I then made some minor changes to the script to make it work without hosting it at a webserver and voilà, it works so far.

If the actual author of the script sees any problem in this and doesn't want me or anyone else to use this, please let me know (I know the username of the original author before the account was deleted).

Comment: Is the new script available for the general public?

Comment: Why not create an account on http://stackapps.com/ and add this script (together with a nice description allowing for it to be found easily by search engines), for the benefit of us all?

Comment: @SergioParreiras oh dear...copyright questions...disclaimer: I am by no means an expert when it comes to copyrights laws, but: the script was hosted as a public GitHub project which is licensed as open source. Although there are different open source licences available, all should allow a private usage, the distribution or hosting for the general public however is a different scenario and may not be permitted. off-topic: this happens when GitHub accounts with open projects get deleted, very confusing and we are left with an unclear licensing state

Comment: @AlexM. I don't think that this would work. While I may use the script for private usage I am most certainly not allowed to host it at [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com/) since this would essentially mean that I would issue a new licence, i guess under the [Creative Commons licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons), for something I didn't own the copyrights in the first place.

Comment: @user190080: The author of that script, who has used several usernames on MSE (the most well known being "NormalHuman"), is still active on Twitter as [NormalHumanSE](https://twitter.com/NormalHumanSE) and he also keeps the blog ["Calculus VII"](https://calculus7.org/). Maybe try contacting him on any of these?

Comment: @AlexM. I really would like to see the above script at [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com/) - I am sure a lot of people would find this very neat - on the other hand I think that NormalHuman probably had specific reasons which lead to the deletion of the associated accounts (SE, GitHub, etc.), so it is likely that NormalHuman doesn't want to get contacted with matters concerning e.g. SE. Also the user didn't upload the script while still active here...If I knew the user personally, this would be different ofc. Again, this is unfortunate but everyone who wants to use the script can do so.

Comment: In september 2019, it doesn't work anymore