# How to copy paste a Mathematics Stack Exchange Answer to Word

Tags: support, export

I have written an answer in Mathematics Stack Exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4215136/955104

So I just want to convert that answer into Word.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can paste text into Word.  Are you asking for some way to convert MathJax markup into a Word document?

Comment: It seems that StackEdit has option to export to HTML - as you can see in the screenshot posted in the answer to this question: [Save the answer in PDF?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15163) Maybe once you have HTML, you could be able to open it into MS Word. (But I wouldn't be overly optimistic.) In general, exporting into TeX/LaTeX seems to be less problematic than exporting into formats such as doc or rtf. For TeX, you can find some suggestions here: [Save the answer in TeX/PDF - revisioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25175).

Comment: You can find some posts concerning converting (La)TeX to at [tex.se], for example, you might check [posts tagged conversion+msword](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion+msword). This post has many views/upvotes/answers: [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4145) Since MathJax is similar to LaTeX, looking at the suggestions given there *might* possible help. (Of course, there are also many major differences. For example, when converting from LaTeX, one issue is to get reference right - this is a non-isue here.)

Comment: I'd guess that it also depends on what exactly you're using in MS Word to enter equations. For example, I read on Wikipedia that [MathType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathType) that "MathType also supports the math markup languages TeX, LaTeX and MathML. LaTeX can be entered directly into MathType, and MathType equations in Microsoft Word can be converted to and from LaTeX." (Disclaimer: The last time I had to use MathType was ages ago - basically, I had to deal with it a bit because a student of mine decided to write his thesis in MS Word.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution using a third party app<sup>1</sup>.

[Mathpix Snip](https://mathpix.com) has the ability to 'Export to .docx', and also allows you to 'Copy MS Word'. Apparently the two give different things and I don't understand what 'Copy MS Word' gives. I also do not have any version of Word. But when I took a screenshot of nearly all your post with the app (its too long for one screenshot) I get

[image]

Clicking on 'Export to .docx' puts a `Doc1.docx` in my `~/Downloads/` folder. When I open it with [Apple Pages](https://www.apple.com/pages/), the text is not sized correctly:

[image]

but on selecting all the text and changing the font size I see something reasonable:

[image]

---

### Notes

1. There is an edit button [image] in the screenshot that allows you to just paste $\rm\LaTeX$ code. Unfortunately, your post was not formatted in correct $\rm\LaTeX$, despite displaying correctly on this site. (Pasting your post into a template `.tex` file shows 16 errors. For example, you cannot have new lines `\\` inside inline math mode `$...$`.) This is because of the difference between $\rm\LaTeX$ and MathJax (and MathJax in my experience is more lenient.)
2. It is not a perfect copy of your post, e.g. Mathpix does not copy `\boxed` correctly. I would suggest to avoid this anyway except perhaps for the final statement of the answer (and it seems you have a comment suggesting this). IMO it is better to stick to basic MathJax/$\rm\LaTeX$ commands unless necessary.
3. Unrelated to your specific query: Mathpix will not copy over any graphs or pictures you have included, which will require manual editing. Sometimes it reads posts wrongly anyway, so you should always read the result once over.
4. As of October 5th 2021 they have a "PDF to Word" option [on the website](https://mathpix.com/blog/pdf-to-word-converter). I haven't tried it; presumably you could print the website as a PDF, and give it a go. They say 20 pages a month are free.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>I feel almost like a shill, especially as there is a paid version of Mathpix, but I'm still happy with the free version at this moment. (And there is no affiliation.)</sup>

Comment: I will just add that MathPix was mentioned on this meta before - although in a different context. See this question: [What tools can be used to extract MathJax/LaTeX from scanned input?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31182) (And also the links given in the answer.)